# What is .bbl bibliography format?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, arxiv

ArXiv requires submission of `.bbl` instead of `.bib`. What is `.bbl` and how is it used with `.tex` files?

Comment: It is a file produced by `bibtex` or `biber`, which is used by `latex` to incorporate the bibliography in your document.

Comment: See the comments and answers in the post [Difference between a .bib and .bbl file for Latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302916/difference-between-a-bib-and-bbl-file-for-latex).

Comment: Just produce your document as normal with `pdflatex` and `bibtex`.  Before uploading, replace `\bibliography{<file>}` by the contents of the `.bbl` file.

Comment: @gernot Are you sure this is a good source?  To me the question and especially the accepted answer are very dodgy.

Comment: Related: https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#bibtex

Comment: @HenriMenke You are right, question and accepted answer are not helpful, but I actually referred to the answer rated highest, which fits the current question quite well.

Comment: @gernot Then you can link to [the answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302918/10995) instead by clicking the »share« button on the bottom left of the answer.  This way, people will directly end up at the specific answer without having to scroll.