# I need a step by step guide to making a bbl file from bib

Tags: bibtex, compiling, bbl

I am trying to merge my tex and bib files into one for a journal submission. Somebody suggested to use the bbl file. I am using texmaker / miktex, and bibtex.

I have no idea as to how to actually create bbl file from bib. All the links I found on this website / google don't actually explicitly explain, step by step, how to do this. And I mean step-by-step (since my knowledge of latex  / computing generally is next to nothing). For example, I see instructions "compile"... And I don't know what this means (as to what key on my keyboard I should be pressing).

Thank you.

Comment: Well regarding "compile" that will be very dependent. If you're using a program designed specifically for writing LaTeX, such as Texmaker (I know you are) it might have a button and/or a keyboard shortcut. But many people use a command line and you can too. What this is called and how to get to it will very from Operating System to Operating System, but if you're using Windows I think it's still called "command prompt". There you would type an instruction. That's the how, what it means in TeX terms is basically turning your LaTeX code into a document

Comment: Yes...The problem is, I still can't see any guide as to how to obtain the bbl file. For example this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324034/what-is-bbl-bibliography-format explains what it is, but not how to obtain and actually find it.@Au101

Comment: Does this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119805/bibliography-in-texmaker

Comment: I know how to run the normal sequence latex, bibtex, latex, etc. That's not a problem. The problem is knowing how and when the bbl file actually appears, and where to find it @Au101

Comment: The `.bbl` file should not be written by you (you *can* tweak it manually, but you shouldn't because your changes will get written over whenever you produce a new revision), it is produced by the `bibtex` program. You have to run `bibtex` on the `.aux` file produced by `pdflatex`

Comment: The `.bbl` file appears after you've run `bibtex`, it is produced by the `bibtex` program, not by you. How is probably not worth going into, but it uses your `.bib` file, the `.aux` file and any `.bst` (style files) you've requested. You will find it in the same folder as your `.tex` file along with the `.log` the `.aux` and other such files that `pdflatex` produces, unless your system is configured to put those files somewhere else so that they don't clutter up your folders, in which case, we need to know more about  your system

Comment: The `.bbl` file will be in your working directory after you've run `bibtex`. Open it, copy the contents into a `thebibliography` environment in the place where you had `\bibliographystyle{<style>}\bibliography{<bibfile>}`.

Comment: That is, copy it, including the `thebibliography` environment. I don't mean to add another one. See my example below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Suppose that we have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{article-crossref} and \cite{article-full}.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Now, we compile in the usual way, using our editor of choice or on the command line or whatever. We make sure that everything is properly resolved and defined, running the compilation sequence multiple times if needed. (Compilation is just running e.g. `pdflatex` -> `bibtex` -> `pdflatex` -> `pdflatex`.)

[image: stage 1]

Now, to prepare the file for journal submission, we open the `.bbl` file, which will be in the working directory, by default, or wherever you've asked for generated files to go.

Here's mine:

```
\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} \newcommand{\printfirst}[2]{#1}
  \newcommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1} \newcommand{\switchargs}[2]{#2#1}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{article-crossref}
L[eslie]~A. Aamport.
\newblock The gnats and gnus document preparation system.
\newblock {\em \mbox{G-Animal's} Journal}, 41(7):73+, July 1986.
\newblock This is a cross-referencing ARTICLE entry.

\bibitem{article-full}
L[eslie]~A. Aamport.
\newblock The gnats and gnus document preparation system.
\newblock {\em \mbox{G-Animal's} Journal}, 41(7):73+, July 1986.
\newblock This is a full ARTICLE entry.

\end{thebibliography}
```

We copy this into our original `.tex` file at the point where we issued the `\bibliographystyle` and `bibliography` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{article-crossref} and \cite{article-full}.
\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} \newcommand{\printfirst}[2]{#1}
  \newcommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1} \newcommand{\switchargs}[2]{#2#1}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{article-crossref}
L[eslie]~A. Aamport.
\newblock The gnats and gnus document preparation system.
\newblock {\em \mbox{G-Animal's} Journal}, 41(7):73+, July 1986.
\newblock This is a cross-referencing ARTICLE entry.

\bibitem{article-full}
L[eslie]~A. Aamport.
\newblock The gnats and gnus document preparation system.
\newblock {\em \mbox{G-Animal's} Journal}, 41(7):73+, July 1986.
\newblock This is a full ARTICLE entry.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Now clean to remove the generated files, so you are sure you aren't still relying on the external `.bbl` and re-compile at least twice (`pdflatex` -> `pdflatex`) to obtain the same result from just your `.tex` file.

Comment: By far the most perfect answer on the Internet. In case you are doing compiling via latex instead of pdflatex, the steps of compilation shall be:  

Filename saved is **main.tex**  
Ref name is **ref.bib**  

`latex main` -> 
`bibtex main` -> 
`latex main` -> 
`latex main` -> 
`dvips main.dvi` -> 
`ps2pdf main.ps main.pdf` 

Rest of the steps remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

In TeXmaker, *a priori*, you only have to write

```
\bibliographystyle{name-of-the-bibstyle}
\bibliography{name-of-the-.bib file}% without the .bib extension
```

in your .tex file, at the place where you want to have your bibliography, then `pdflatex (F6) + bibtex (F11) + pdflatex (twice)` on the .tex file. Alternatively you can choose `Fast compilation`, which will do that automatically for you.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I *think* the issue is that the OP doesn't know how to eliminate the dependency on the `.bib` file. Could be mistaken, though, of course.

Comment: @cfr: it's me who misunderstood. However, if the OP knows about .bib files and .bibtex, he/she would have noticed the creation of a .bbl file, don't you think?

Comment: The problem is that Texmaker does not show all file name extensions. The bbl. file was hidden - that was half of my problem@Bernard

Comment: That's not a problem of TeXmaker, but of Windows configuration. It's always better to ask showing file extensions (I believe they're hidden by default).

Comment: OS X tends to hide file extensions, too, if I remember correctly. (Perhaps I'm imagining it.) It certainly presents the underlying file-system in deeply misleading ways in Finder. Anyway, how often do you examine the contents of the working directory with a fine-tooth comb? If you know that is where it will be, you'll look. But if you don't know to look there, but believe it is something you need to create in some different way, then you won't know where to begin.

Comment: Yes exactly - I didn't know where to start @cfr