# use bibtex without a bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am following the [instructions to submit a paper to JASA](https://asa.scitation.org/pb-assets/files/publications/jas/jasinfcon-1518211773377.pdf). In "II. ONLINE HANDLING OF MANUSCRIPTS
" under "C. Preparation for online submission" they write:

> Properly prepared manuscript/article file in LaTeX
> or Word format. Authors who wish to use LaTeX
> should use the JASA LaTeX package, which is
> available here: http://acousticalsociety.org/preparinglatex-manuscripts/. (The requirements for a properly
> prepared manuscript are given further below.) It must be
> a single stand-alone file. If the author wishes to submit
> a LaTeX file, the references should be included in the
> file, not in a separate BibTeX file. Authors should take
> care to ensure that the submitted manuscript/article file
> is of reasonable length.

All of their supplementary materials, which can be found [here](https://acousticalsociety.org/preparing-latex-manuscripts/) only give examples using BibTex. My paper is also using BibTex. Is there any way to include the references into the tex file? Am I missing something?

Comment: A BibTeX run produces a `.bbl` file that contains the bibliography environment `\begin{thebibliography}...\end{thebibliography}` in printable format. Often publishers just want you to paste the contents of the `.bbl` file into your `.tex` source at the point where you have the `\bibliography` call.

Comment: There must be an explanation for this somewhere. Overleaf have something: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/The_journal_says_%22don't_use_BibTeX;_paste_the_contents_of_the_.bbl_file_into_the_.tex_file%22._How_do_I_do_this_on_Overleaf%3F, but maybe there is a more graphic explanation here on TeX.SX ...

Comment: Here is something: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329198/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351483/35864

Comment: @moewe, care to make this an answer so I can give you the credit?

Comment: I'd probably close the question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329198/35864, if that would be alright with you.

Comment: sure. Should I delete or is it better to close it?

Comment: I think duplicates still remain searchable, so it is better to close as a duplicate than to delete the question.