# Add bbl file entries to latex document

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I have a main file with a corresponding bib file. Now I want to cite items that are found in an already compiled `bbl` file. How could one combine the 2?

Ideas:

1. Add the new `\bibitem` to `main.bbl` file, deletes entries upon recompiling
2. Can one combine multiple bib/bbl files?
3. Convert bbl files to bib by hand as an answer suggest

Comment: You have tagged your question with `biblatex`, but parts of what I say can also be applied to BibTeX: The `.bbl` file contains the entries in sorted order, if you want to merge several `.bbl`s it would take some time to get the sort order right. Furthermore for `biblatex` the `.bbl` may include context-dependent information such as name uniqueness and disambiguation information, if entries from different `.bbl`s are merged these pieces of information can't be guaranteed to be correct any more.

Comment: The question mentions `\bibitem`, which is a BibTeX command and not used in `biblatex`, explicitly while it is tagged with `biblatex`. Do you use `biblatex` and only used `\bibitem` as a metonymy or do you use BibTeX (and mistagged the question)?

Answer (score 5):

#### What do `.bbl` files do?

`.bbl` files are the intermediate data format used to make `.bib` entries usable in a LaTeX file. Their format and exact use differs between `biblatex` and BibTeX-based systems.

For BibTeX-based systems (e.g. `natbib`) the `.bbl` file contains a `thebibliography` environment that can be typeset directly. Usually `thebibliography` is a glorified `enumerate` environment with a few extra `\label`-like commands. The `.bbl` file is (essentially) `\input` by `\bibliography{...}` and typeset as is. The format and contents of the `.bbl` file are controlled by the `.bst` you gave in `\bibliographystyle` in your document. BibTeX's `.bbl` files can be easily edited by hand, indeed the 'manual bibliography method' essentially consists of writing the contents of a `.bbl` directly into the document (see for example https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94mori.pdf).

For `biblatex` the `.bbl` file does not contain typesettable code, instead it contains the original data in a digested format usable for `biblatex`. The `.bbl` file is read at the beginning of the document so that all information about all entries is available while the document is processed. Since `biblatex` allows you to separate your document into several `refsection`s and supports getting data from different `refcontext`s, the structure of the file can be slightly more complicated than a simple list of all entries with their data. Still ultimately, `biblatex`'s `.bbl` files are a text-based list structure that can be edited manually if need be.

See also [Difference between a .bib and .bbl file for Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302916/35864), [How tell LaTeX to use existing bbl file without running bibtex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99726/35864). I have touched on this in [Customize citation with bibulous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459161/35864), [Making the arXiv accept a BibTeX BBL (May 2018)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429436/35864) and [Can a LaTeX file include the BibTeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454035/35864) and you will probably find many more posts on this site that explain this or mention how `.bbl`s work in passing or in more detail.

#### Difficulties in merging several `.bbl` files

One important thing to keep in mind is that both the `.bbl` files for BibTeX and `biblatex` are sorted. That means that you must pay attention to the sort order when you merge two `.bbl` files (by whatever means).

Furthermore `.bbl` files may contain data not present in the `.bib` that goes beyond sorting. For `biblatex` that includes name uniqueness and disambiguation data. Some more advanced author-year BibTeX styles also create year disambiguation labels like the "a" and "b" in "Knuth 1986a, Knuth 1986b" on the fly. If new entries are added, these context-dependent features may not behave as expected any more. Another example of data that is not present in the `.bib` file itself and calculated by the backend are the alphanumeric labels as produced by `alpha.bst` or `style=alphabetic`.

For BibTeX-based `.bbl` files it would be good if the output of the two `.bbl` files was compatible so that the output is consistent. This is a given if both `.bbl`s were produced with the same `.bst`, if that is not the case, manual interventions might be needed. Since `biblatex`'s `.bbl` files contain only data, this is not a concern for `biblatex`.

#### Pasting the contents of `.bbl` file one into file two

The simple solution to merging `.bbl` files is to just copy the contents of one `.bbl` file into another.

Since `.bbl` files are intended as an auxiliary and temporary bridge between the `.bib` and the `.tex` file they are supposed to be overwritten by each BibTeX or Biber run. That means that it is tedious, if very straightforward for BibTeX and fairly straightforward for `biblatex`, to make manual changes to these files.

All in all I would say this approach is viable if you have only few entries to integrate into your `.bbl` file and context-sensitive data and sorting play little or no role.

#### Loading several `.bbl` files with LaTeX

It is no problem to load several `.bbl` files with BibTeX, but if you do not manipulate the involved macros, both files will produce separate bibliographies with their own numbering

```
\begin{document}
\cite{sarfraz,kullback}
\cite{doody,wilde}
\input{bblone.bbl}
\input{bbltwo.bbl}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two separate bibliographies]

Depending on the desired output it might be possible to hack something together that would combine the two `.bbl` files (more or less) (this is just a proof of concept and absolutely *not recommended*, it redefines low level commands in a very naive way)

```
\begin{document}
\cite{sarfraz,kullback}
\cite{doody,wilde}
\makeatletter
\begingroup
% usually \begin{...}\end{...} has an implicit group, we need to get rid of that
\def\begin#1{\csname #1\endcsname}
\def\end#1{\csname end#1\endcsname}
% save the real endthebibliography and disable the end for the first bbl
\let\orig@endthebibliography\endthebibliography
\let\endthebibliography\relax
\input{bblone.bbl}
% remove the beginning and restore the end
\let\thebibliography\@gobble
\let\endthebibliography\orig@endthebibliography
\input{bbltwo.bbl}
\endgroup
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image: One combined bibliography]

With `biblatex` it is possible to obtain the data from different `.bbl` files as well, see [How to import / print a bibliography created from a separate / external document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426964/35864). But it is more complicated to get things right due to the more complex structure.

So it is theoretically possible to combine `.bbl`s on the the LaTeX side, but that might get very complicated quite quickly and does not solve the issues of sorting and context dependent information.

#### Converting the `.bbl` to `.bib`

My preference would be to convert the contents of your second `.bbl` back to a `.bib` file. With that `.bib` file you can then use BibTeX or Biber as usual.

The conversion does not have to be done by hand, you can use https://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/ as suggested in [Convert from a textplain reference to bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233442/35864). Of course you have to double check the result and should expect to have to apply some fixes to the result, but as a first approach such a tool can be helpful. The good thing is that you only have to do this once.

There is no issue with loading several `.bib` files at once, see [Bibliographies from multiple .bib files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84099/35864).