# Multiple bibliographies using BibTeX and thebibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm wondering if it is possible to have multiple bibliography without me needed to update a `references.bib` file.

I have a main `references.bib` that contains most of my references, however, since I am combining multiple older latex files together that contain `thebibliography` environments.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \textit{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd edition,
  1994.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I think in the future i will be more consistent in the way I make citations, but I am wondering if there is a way to make both `thebibliography` and separate bib files work together, or at bare minimum convert `thebibliography` to valid BibTeX references.

Comment: You can just input the old `thebibliography` environments in addition to using `\bibliography{references}`

Comment: In theory you can have both `\bibliography{...}` and a `thebibliography` environment in your document. But by default the numbering in both will start at 1 and it is not easily possible to sort the two to combine into one big bibliography.

Comment: This question is basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464284/35864 (the only difference being that in the linked question the `thebibliography` is hidden in a `.bbl` file and in your question it is explicit in the document).

Comment: Thec regular BibTeX procedure produces an thebibliography environment in the bbl  file. In your case I would use it and consolidate all the thebibliography into a single one by an easy copy paste in the editor, assuming that there are not to much double that must be fixed by hand. Or if you want to keep them separate, have a look to the multibib package.