# Merge bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have the problem that I have several(!) bibliographies of the following format (more references in them of course)

> ```
> \begin{thebibliography}{0}
>   \bibitem[A]{A04} J.~E.~Avron, (2004).
>   \emph{Colored Hofstadter butterflies.} TrendsMath.
>   Boston, MA: Birkh\"auser Boston, pp. 11-22.
> \end{thebibliography}
> ```

but also one bibliography in a bibtex file that I can access by calling in the .tex file

> ```
> \bibliography{biblio}
> ```

My question is: Is there a way to combine all these bibliographies in one bibliography, so that they appear as one in the paper?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify your document setup: Is it the case that you have (a) several hand-built bibliographies of the form `\begin{thebibliography}{nn} ... \end{thebibliography}` as well as (b) a bibliography that's generated by BibTeX (which would require both a `\bibliography` and a `\bibliographystyle` directives)? How do you `\cite` entries in the bib file? Please advise.

Comment: Essentially this is the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464284/35864. While it is possible to merge `thebibliography` and BibTeX-generated `.bbl` files, it would probably be a lot of work to merge them manually, since in `thebibliography` you are responsible for sorting and everything. It might be better to make your manual `thebibliography` `\bibitem`s available in a `.bib` file and let BibTeX generate the entire bibliography. That way you could be reasonably certain that things are sorted correctly and that the output is consistent.